# How to upload and overlay animation.html file from system and overlay over video in HTML or ANGULAR

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ffmpeg, html5-canvas

Hey I am trying to build an app which has a functionality of allowing a user to upload a pre-existing .HTML file from his system which contains a simple animation init

I want to get that file and overlay the animation contained in .HTML file on my video and display it to the user.

is that possible please help me if it is.

```css
body {
  background: #;
}

#fullScreenBox {
  height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  background: #;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

#hiddenBox {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  background: #;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#title {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #;
  /*U can also use #*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
}

#subtitle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #;
  /*U can also use #*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
}

#line01 {
  width: 25%;
  height: 4px;
  background: white;
  /*U can also use #*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  background: #;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

#v {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body data-control="10:30">

  <div id="fullScreenBox">
    <div id="overlay" class="">
      <div id="title" class="webvfx" data-animate='{
                start: 0,
                end: 1,
                ease: "linearTween",
                0%: {opacity:0; left:-1000px;},
                20%: {opacity: 1; left:0px;},
                90%: {opacity:1; left:0px;},
                100%: {opacity: 0; left:1000px;}
            }'>
        LONDON
      </div>
      <div id="line01" class="webvfx" data-animate='{
                start: 0,
                end: 1,
                ease: "linearTween",
                0%: {opacity:1; width: 0%;},
                20%: {opacity:1; width: 25%;},
                80%: {opacity:1; width: 25%;},
                100%: {opacity:1; width: 0%;}
            }'>

      </div>

      <div id="subtitle" class="webvfx" data-animate='{
                start: 0,
                end: 1,
                ease: "linearTween",
                0%: {opacity:0; left:1000px;},
                20%: {opacity: 1; left:0px;},
                90%: {opacity:1; left:0px;},
                100%: {opacity: 0; left:-1000px;}
            }'>
        City of Dreams!
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my HTML file that contains a simple animation for example which is in user system

In my application when user upload this file i want to overlay the animation contained in this file on the video as he uploads it is these any way
Thank you

Comment: Wait, what do you mean HTML that contains an animation? HTML files contain text, not animations. And what animation are you talking about? Gif? Video? What video format? MP4? Then you want to take this, and overlay it in another video? What video? How do you implement it? Where's your code?

Comment: Now You can re-check the post @Jeremy Thille

Comment: Ah I see, so that's a standalone CSS animation. I know no way of loading an external file inside a page, except maybe inside an iframe? I don't know but it sounds hard to do anyway!

Comment: yes it quite hard to do tho it contains  only text so maybe trying to find a way.
Thank you for you help